# Making changes live on dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

So, I am new to this programming stuff and I am working on my company's website. I was given the files to it from the previous person who worked on it before me and I'm using dreamweaver because that's what they used. So I have everything connected to our webserver, but every time I try to make my changes live, nothing happens. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've also emptied the cache and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the changes to your previous code, you need to modify the HTML code, save it and then show it live to see the changes.

For the professional jobs I suggest you to use Aptana and Web-storms.